# How to install Windows Movie Maker for XP?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-movie-maker

I'm running Windows XP SP3. I want to install Movie Maker, but apparently it comes with SP2. I looked around, but it doesn't seem to be installed. There's a `movie maker` folder in `Program Files` that has a bunch of DLLs and a `shared` folder with some stuff, but no executable. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Windows Movie Maker is now part of the Windows Live package. You can get it by downloading the Windows Live installer, see:

http://explore.live.com/windows-live-movie-maker?os=other

Unfortunately though you need Windows Vista or 7 to use the newest version. You should still be able to download the old Xp version from http://downloads.cnet.co.uk/view/video-software/windows-movie-maker-windows-xp-39059185/ though.

Comment: Unless I'm doing something wrong, the Download links just lead back to Microsoft's site.

Comment: So it does, the only other link I can find which does seem to work is ftp://ftp.microsoft.com.ar/so/mm20enu.exe (from the external links section of the wikipedia page on Movie Maker http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Movie_Maker#Windows_XP).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's website advises it can be obtained from Windows Updates: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/updates/moviemaker2.mspx

Comment: I went to the Microsoft Update site, but it wasn't listed in the software updates. Where specifically should I look?

Answer (score 0):

Movie Maker should be in *Add/Remove Programs → Windows Components*. Make sure you have the XP install media.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to sit around waiting for Windows Updates to randomly reinstal Moviemaker, you can restore MovieMaker 2.1 yourself to Windows XP SP3 by re-installing Service Pack 3.

There is no freestanding MovieMaker 2.1 for XP that I know of, in fact that's what I'm looking for. But, I've looked before, and no luck.  (Also, I tried an alleged freestanding one that somebody invented by himself, but it was a mess, not for XP at all.)

Microsoft offers Service Pack 3 as an executable download:

This is the file:  WindowsXP-KB936929-SP3-x86-ENU.exe

It's a big file, 316.4 MB.

Download it here:  http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=24

Don't worry that it says Network installation, this file works.

Be sure to follow the instructions carefully, such as first back up your system.  And keep this file handy on a backup flash drive, you don't want to lose it when Microsoft stops support for XP next year.

I used this SP3 fix to repair MovieMaker 2.1 in my Dell Latitude D600 laptop running XP, and to completely add it to an older Lenovo Thinkpad running XP that didn't have it.

Another good resource for you would be:

http://www.windowsmoviemakers.net/

There are a couple of experts there who can help you with anything, including creating and adding your own effects, titles, subtitles and transitions to Moviemake.

It's a really cool forum, that's where they told me how to instal Service Pack 3 to fix MovieMaker.

Have yourself a great day!

Comment: The forum has nothing to do with the authors questiion.  Besides this answer is more a response than an answer